# Oozie: FAILED: IllegalArgumentException java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:./tmp

Tags: oozie, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to use Hive action in Oozie, but even a very simple hive script got this error in the error log:

''FAILED: IllegalArgumentException java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:./tmp/..''

So is there any smart and simple solution for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you post your "very simple **Oozie** script" nobody will be able to help you correct it...

Comment: my script is called test.sql, inside there is only one sentence:

Comment: the sentence is: show databases;

Comment: I wrote **Oozie**, not **Hive**. Meaning the damn XML that you have submitted to the Oozie server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running into a bug with Oozie:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2380

I have not found a workaround for this other than applying this patch.